# Control multiple divs from select menu (multiple times on a page)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to  show hide multiple divs from a select menu. I have it working fine, except it only works the first time it appears on the page. After that it just shows all the divs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#part_update').change(function() {
            $("#update_form div:not('.alwaysShow')").hide();
            $("#update_form .show" + $('#part_update').val()).show();
        });

        $('#part_update').change(); // simulate a change event to trigger the above
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
//WRITE THE ROW WITH THE ADDITIONAL OPTIONS FOR EDITING
echo '<tr id="row'.$list[part_no].'" style="display:none" class="options_row">
    <td colspan="7">
        <form name="fm'.$list[part_no].'" id="update_form" class="updateContainer" method="post" action="process_pm.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="cur_cat" value="'.$_GET[cat].'">
            <input type="hidden" name="show" value="'.$_GET[show].'">
            <input type="hidden" name="pagenum" value="'.$_GET[pagenum].'">
            <input type="hidden" name="findtype" value="'.$_GET[findtype].'">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="part_no" value="'.$list[part_no].'" />
            <div class="alwaysShow">
                <select id="part_update" >
                    <option value="Add" >Add New Inventory</option>
                    <option value="Update">Update Existing Inventory</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="showAdd" >
                <label for="part_cost">&nbsp;$</label><input type="text" name="part_cost" id="part_cost" class="help" title="Enter Total Invoice Cost" >
            </div>
            <div class="showAdd showUpdate" ><input type="text" name="part_qty" id="part_qty" class="help" title="Enter Qty" ></div>
            <div class="showUpdate" >
                <input name="update_type" type="radio" value="add_qty" checked> Add
                <input name="update_type" type="radio" value="set_qty" > Set
            </div>
            <div class="alwaysShow"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="alwaysShow" value="Submit"></div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:hideDiv(\'row'.$list[part_no].'\');" /><img src="support/btn-update-close.png" />Close</a>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`id`s are meant to be unique, i.e. they should only occur once on the page. What you want to use there is a `class` instead:

```
$('.part_update').change(function() {
    /* so on and so forth... */
}
```

Obviously there's nothing preventing you from using the same `id` in various spots on the page, but as you can see, it's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. I completely overlooked the form name. I updated code to use class instead, but it still exhibits the same behavior. Works the first time you switch, but if you use another instance of it, it will stick in the opposite state. Maybe use toggle instead?